# Display the last joined entity columns in Twig template

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm making a website for performance monitoring, so every months people's fill their performances and this create a graph in JavaScript.

I did a ManyToOne relation between performances entity and users entity. As you can see here:

I would like to display the performances of one user for example I use this code in Twig (and after I would like to know how to display the latest performances).

Entity performances:

[image]

```html
    {% for user in users  %}

      <h4>{{ user.username|upper }}</h4>
      <p>Ville: {{ user.performances.ville  }}</p>
      <p>Taille: {{ user.performances.taille  }}</p>

 {% endfor %}
```

```html
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="descriptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="users_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;
```

But it don't works, can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access to the last item of your `user.performances` collection :

```
{% for user in users  %}
    <h4>{{ user.username|upper }}</h4>
    <p>Ville: {{ user.performances.last.ville  }}</p>
    <p>Taille: {{ user.performances.last.taille  }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You can do the same with `first` for the first item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is that possible to get the data for a special month, for exemple if the user fill up his performances every months ?